# ¿Cuándo conviene utilizar break y continue en Java?

Tags: java, bucles

Estoy estudiando estas características del lenguaje (`break` y `continue`), y aunque las entiendo, me cuesta encontrar un ejemplo práctico en donde poder utilizarlas. He visto tutoriales por la web pero son todos ejemplos que se podrían solventar poniendo alguna bandera booleana en el bucle y utilizando instrucciones condicionales. ¿En qué casos utilizar estas dos instrucciones suponen una ventaja?

Gracias, y que sigan bien.

Comment: break, continue y goto rompen con el paradigma de programación estructurada, es verdad que existen y funcionan pero nunca debieran utilizarse, es una mala práctica, digamos que es algo así como un antipatron

Comment: Pueden considerarse un atajo. Como dices, todos los ejemplos pueden resolverse usando otras alternativas así que su ventaja es la brevedad que representan.

Comment: La única ventaja que tienes usando `break` y `continue` es precisamente la simplificación del código que obtienes al evitar la variable booleana y la condición sobre la misma. Si no ves esa simplificación como algo importante, sino al revés. no los uses.

Comment: Voy a usar las estructuras de control de siempre. Lo voy a estudiar un poco más sólo para el caso en donde tenga que leer el código de otras personas y estás características sean utilizadas. Gracias a todos.

Comment: esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones por lo tanto votare para que la cierren; solo generan discusiones sin sentido; si desea una respuesta asertiva verifique los actuales estándares de programación y apéguese a uno que contemple el uso de correcto de break y continúe; o siga las buenas practicas de los ingenieros de software: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices

Comment: Tenemos dos respuestas que son totalmente opuestas. Esta pregunta no tiene sentido practico y depende de las opiniones de quienes contesten. Es mas, hay literatura en los dos sentidos.

Comment: @gbianchi, no se iba a cerrar la publicación?

Answer (score 3):

Realmente depende de lo que estés haciendo.
En algunos casos tener un **break** o un **continue** puede hacer que sea más difícil entender el flujo del código. Sin embargo, hay oportunidades en las que es mucho más práctico. Usarlas no es mala práctica de programación, siempre y cuando estés escribiendo código legible.

Imagina que tienes que recorrer un string **s** , encontrar la primera instancia de un carácter específico e insertarla al final de otro string **s2**.

```
for (char c : s) {
    if (c == ‘a’) {
        s2 += c;
        break;
    }
}
```

Si lo comparamos con la alternativa, nos podemos dar cuenta que usando el **break** es mucho más fácil saber que está pasando y es menos propenso a errores.

```
boolean found = false;
for (char c : s) {
    if (c == ‘a’ && !found) {
        s2 += c;
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Este es un ejemplo sencillo, donde se evidencia  que es más legible la primera opción. No solo no tenemos que declarar variables innecesarias, sino que también estamos iterando únicamente las veces que necesitamos.

Comment: Socio usar el break y el continue si es una mala practica y no deben usarse

Comment: Para referirnos a la literatura, podrías echar un vistazo a Structured Programming with go to statements de Donald Knuth, quien habla del tema, y muestra ejemplos de escenarios en los que conviene usar estas estructuras. Es simplemente una herramienta más que hay que saber usar. :)

Comment: Bueno digamos que hay dos escuelas de pensamiento, tu eres de una y yo de otra    :)