# pedir un elemento si lo contiene

Tags: java

```html
String colores[]={"azul","rojo","gris","verde","morado"};
        String guardar="";
        System.out.print("Ingrese color: ");
        String color=entrada.nextLine();
        for (int i=0;i<colores.length;i++){
            if (color.equals(colores[i])){
                guardar=colores[i];
                //guardar=color;
            }else{
                guardar="blanco";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(guardar);
```

si escribo un color que contiene el array colores muestro ese color que escribi, si no contiene un color del array colores muestra color blanco.
ahora no se cual es el error porque de las dos maneras me muestra color blanco.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuándo conviene utilizar break y continue en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429832/cu%c3%a1ndo-conviene-utilizar-break-y-continue-en-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sucede en que si por ejemplo vos ingresas `rojo` en la segunda iteracion `guardar` tomara ese valor, sin embargo el ciclo aun se estaria ejecutandose hasta llegar a `morado` el cual es diferente de `color`el cual tomo el valor de `rojo` y por ende te devolvera `blanco`(else),pero que pasaria si ingresas morado bueno tu salida seria morado por que al coincidir en la ultima iteracion te devolvera ese valor

```
  String colores[]={"azul","rojo","gris","verde","morado"};
```

Podrias poner un punto de interrupcion break; en tu codigo para que ni bien encuentre coincidencia con el color te devuelva ese valor

```
for (int i=0;i<colores.length;i++){
            if (color.equals(colores[i])){
                guardar=colores[i];
                break;
        
            }else{
                guardar="blanco";
            }
```

o podrias declarar el valor por defecto en guardar como blanco y asi evitar el uso de else

```
String guardar="blanco";
        System.out.print("Ingrese color: ");
        String color=entrada.nextLine();
        for (int i=0;i<colores.length;i++){
            if (color.equals(colores[i])){
                guardar=colores[i];
              
            }
        }
```

Comment: gracias, resulta que a break lo conozco pero no se paso por la mente utilizarlo, gracias